# Simplifying systemd kernel command paramters

Tags: grub2, systemd

I use the following kernel command line parameters in grub (Ubuntu 18.04)

`nomodeset iommu=off transparent_hugepage=never systemd.mask=ModemManager.service systemd.mask=whoopsie.service systemd.mask=irqbalance service systemd.mask=cups.socket systemd.mask=cups.path systemd.mask=cups.service systemd.mask=cups-browsed.service systemd.mask=packagekit.service systemd.mask=unattended-upgrades.service systemd.mask=speech-dispatcher.service systemd.mask=setvtrgb.service systemd.mask=kerneloops.service systemd.mask=apport.service systemd.mask=apt-daily-upgrade.timer systemd.mask=apt-daily.timer systemd.mask=motd-news.timer system.mask=systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer systemd.mask=ua-timer.timer 3`

Is there a way to combine all these individual systemd.mask= arguments?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can mask services without using grub. Simply mask the services you don't think you'll need by executing in a normal shell:

`systemctl mask any.service`

where 'any' is the name of the service to be masked. Systemd will store this info, so it is not necessary to execute those commands after every boot or pass the information to systemd using the kernel command line in e.g. grub.

Still, disabling the services should suffice: once a service is disabled, it won't start itself on boot, but you could start it manually or another systemd unit like a service, socket, etc. could start it by requiring it. Masking a service will prevent you and systemd units from starting it (in case you need it in a rare occasion). To disable (not mask) a service, do:

`systemctl disable any.service`

If you suddenly decide to print, you could `start` the cups service, for example. (It won't start on the next boot, since it is still disabled)

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer to temporarily disable services for a specific kernel only. Not on a global level.